# XCode 9.1 Hang on load Storyboard Signing product issue

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode9, xcode9.1

Folks,

Currently I am using xcode 9.1 version when working into .h,.m or .swift file projects works properly even when run application into device works without any error.

Also same project open into `XCODE 8` It's works `.storyboard` open and able to edit every thing works But when I loaded my project in `Xcode 9.1`  I try to load my main storyboard, Xcode starts to compile automatically the storyboard and it's hanging in the step **"Signing product"**. After that i Have to force the exit.

NOTE : I used project developed into `XCODE 8.3.3` after updating xcode newer version `XCODE 9` or `XCODE 9.1` facing this kind of issue.

Anybody having the same issue or like that?

Any solution to fix this issue/bug while updating `.storyboard` code.

Answer (score 2):

For the issue,

I have analyse a thing here sharing:

1. Remove old Xcode's from your system, if it requires then save it dmg file for future purpose.
2. In Activity monitor, don't exceed the source kit size more than 700 mb if exceeds force quit it.
3. Restart your Xcode 2 or 3 times in a day, this will stops long time process(which Xcode uses) from which it hangs.
4. Upgrade your RAM if you really required more than 8 GB.

Still I am also facing issues not frequently, but these are worked for me, so I sharing.

Comment: Thanks @gouravjoshi I already using 16 GB RAM and this kind of issue happen into large size of storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue specifically when I called "Refresh All Views" from the Interface Builder (but NOT when building/running on device) when I had a custom UIButton class. I overrode `layoutSubviews()`, and inside that method I was calling `self.titleLabel?.font` to set the button label's font size.

Apparently, this caused my issue, and after some researching on the Apple developer forums I learned that updating a UI element's content inside `layoutSubviews()` is inadvisable.

See: [these answers](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/160829#160829).

Comment: +1000000 thanks - this was my issue. The only way I could make this change was to open the file directly and comment out `layoutSubviews()`